# Problems loading page with jQuery's pageinit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing a script for mobile using jQuery Mobile's "pageinit" to load my scripts. I am using EJS for my view templates. I have created two pages using jQuery's data-role="page". The 1st page is a dynamically created list of classrooms. I attach an event Listener to each list item that brings you to the 2nd page, which is a list of that classrooms students. To get the student data I make an ajax call based on the given classroom ID. This kinda works.

My problem is that the 1st time and only the 1st time loading the student data after restarting the application; the data sent back from the ajax call is not loaded into the list. I have tested that it is sent with an alert on a successful ajax call. I am using "pageinit" to load the script.

This is the basic structure of my EJS file I am working with:

```
  <body>
   <div data-role="page" id="classroomMaster">
       <div data-role="header">
           <-- some navigation elements -->
       </div>

       <div data-role="content">

           <-----*this is a dynamically created clickable list, which I set 
                    an eventListener for in the first part of my script* ----->

           <% for(var i=0; i<classRooms.length; i++) { %>
               <li id=<%= classRooms[i].ID %> >
                    <a href="" data-ajax="false"><%= classRooms[i].ID %></a>                    
               </li>
           <% } %>  
       </div>   
   </div>

   <div data-role="page" id="studentList">

       <div data-role="content" id="students">
            <% if(typeof studentRecords != 'undefined') { %>

           <-----*studentRecords is not defined initially, after a classRoom link from
                  the first page is selected an ajax call is made to return the studentRecords objects* ------------>

                 <ul data-role="listview">
                     <% for(var i=0; i<studentRecords.length; i++) { %>
                         <li id=<%= studentRecords[i].ID %> >
                              <a href=""><%= studentRecords[i].ID %></a>
                         </li>
                     <% } %>    
                 </ul>
            <% } %>
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

This is the script that I am using

```
var currentList;
var elementID;
var id;

$( document ).on( "pageinit", '#mowingmaster', function( event ) {

    $('li').each(function(index) {

        var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
        elementID = '#' + elementID;

        $(function() {      
            $(elementID).click(function(event) {

                var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
                id = elementID;
                elementID = '#' + elementID;

                setElementID(id);
                $.mobile.changePage("#dailylist");
            });
        });
    });

    $( "#dailylist" ).on( "pagebeforeshow", function( event, ui) { 
        $("#testhide").hide()
        setCurrentList(elementID);
    });

    $( "#dailylist" ).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {
        //Do nothing
    });
});

function setElementID(id) {
    id = id;
}

function setCurrentList() {
    var currentList = id;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/scape/mowinglist",
        data: {currentList : currentList},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            $("#testlist").listview("refresh");
        }
    });
};
```

This problem only happens the first time loading the page after restarting the application.
I have tried every combination of Jquery's different ways of loading pages (pageshow, pagechange, many more) also trying document and the page ID as my selector. I have tried refreshing the listview. I also tried a couple different ways to try to use callbacks to get the information loaded to the page at the correct time. I found a couple similar examples with this problem and their solution of putting the code for the ajax call in a different or separate pageinit/pageshow/pagechange call always made the eventListeners on the list of classrooms no longer work.

If any additional code or information is needed, I will be here. I appreciate you taking the time to read this. Thank You very much for any suggestions, information or help that anyone can provide. I am self teaching so any suggestions towards my code at all are appreciated.

Comment: You call it like this setCurrentList(elementID); , but you implement it like this setCurrentList(). Doesn't your console log complains?

Comment: You don't have to use a semicolon in the implementation of your function.

Comment: @alkis no it doesn't log complaints and I have changed that problem. I do not know what I was thinking there. Is it possible to load dynamic data into the list the way I am trying? I've read the documentation and looked at examples but nothing is exactly what I need or I am missing something fundamental

Comment: To be honest I'm still trying to follow your code. Your script begins on the init of mowingmaster. Shouldn't that be classroomMaster?

Comment: Please update your js section with the code that you have right now.

Comment: @alkis yes. I simplified the context for my question to make it easier to explain. Sorry for the lazy mistake. It should be classroomMaster, and the code is ugly. It's what I do to code when it doesnt work..i just try everything. I will make a few more small updates now to try to make it clearer

Comment: Don't worry about it. You are doing pretty good considered the fact that you are self taught and a beginner. Just update your code (with some formatting please, so it's readable) and post a comment so I get a notification.

Comment: Why are you using $(function() { inside init? Check this for understanding what that means http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/22/function%E2%80%A6-vs-function%E2%80%A6-or-domready-vs-the-module-pattern/

Comment: I believe that's the problem. Please remove it, and see what happens.

Comment: @alkis that did not do it. I grazed that article enough to understand it could not be helping my situation. I will give a more in depth look after I update my code

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentList;
var elementID;
var id;

$( document ).on( "pageinit", '#classroomMaster', function( event ) {

    $('li').each(function(index) {

        var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
        elementID = '#' + elementID;


        $(elementID).click(function(event) {

            var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
            id = elementID;
            elementID = '#' + elementID;

            setElementID(id);
            $.mobile.changePage("#dailylist");
        });
    });

    $( "#dailylist" ).on( "pagebeforeshow", function( event, ui) { 
        $("#testhide").hide()
        setCurrentList(elementID);
    });

    $( "#dailylist" ).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {
        //Do nothing
    });
});

function setElementID(id) {
    id = id;
}

function setCurrentList(id) {
    var currentList = id;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/scape/mowinglist",
        data: {currentList : currentList},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            $("#testlist").listview("refresh");
        }
    });
}
```